# How to populate reference stored in different collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, relationship, nodejs-server

I have a following monogodb collections

```
coll1       coll2
--------     -------
_id          _id
name         coll1_ids
```

coll2 can have multiple reference to coll1 but coll1 will only have one reference

I want to populate coll2 data in coll1. Is there easier way to do it without using aggregation in Node.js.
Thank you!!!

Comment: Without aggregation, you will have to query multiple times, which can create an unnecessary load on the database. Any specific reason, why you don't want to use aggregation pipeline?

Comment: With aggregation, I'm having the same issue. It is taking too much time.

Comment: Time is a function of the collection size. Do you want to update the documents in collection1 permanently, or it's just a requirement of an api.

Comment: It is just required for API

Comment: Then you must benchmark the current schema, and then a modified version, where you store the data in a single collection. I think that might be good for you.

Comment: Also, if you can add your current aggregation based query, maybe we can suggest some optimizations there.

Comment: `coll1_ids` field in coll2 is an array of ids of multiple documents from coll1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Mongoose `virtual`, you need to define `virtual` in coll1 schema and you can use those `virtual` in `populate` like below for example

```
coll1Schema.virtual('coll2Data', {
    ref: "coll2",
    localField: "_id",
    foreignField: "coll1_ids"
});
```

then you need to pass that virtual name in Mongoose populate function for example

```
Coll1.find().populte("coll2Data")
```

More clarification about mongoose `virtual` visit this link https://thecodebarbarian.com/mongoose-4.13-virtual-populate-dynamic-refs-fields

Answer (score 0):

for speed, you can also use indexing in MongoDB.

- https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/indexes/

and if you use Mongoose for MongoDB connection then you can use Populate also

- https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

[enter link description here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)